# Is my POST response is delivered to client

Tags: php, api, post

So, I'm trying to figure out, is it possible to know that my response was successfully delivered to client.
What we have is about 20 POS systems (written in different technologies, such as dot.net and java) that sending POST request to our API (php/yii). When we responding to those requests we want to know is the response successfully delivered.
We need this because there can be a situation, when we charging customer, but the POS don't know about that, and can stay stuck with open order. We can't be sure that POS will send another request and we can't mess with POS code.
If we know that the response is not delivered, we can roll back the charging.
Is it possible with basic POST request?
As I said, our project is in php, but code snippets or documentation in any other language is accepted. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think this can be done without modifying client side code.

Comment: I think so too, but I have to ask... After all the post request is some sort of socket connection, and may be you can determine is the connection ended properly or it was interrupted in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Two Generals' Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) and there is no common right answer to these types of question. But you can make it mandatory to get to a level in the conversation where the lack of contact would not induce/prohibit vital action, only the re-send/re-request of acknowledgments.

Here you do not have a good choice to do this. A better way to go was that once the server gets a full request for a transaction, it is executed; regardless of the client's state. When the POS does not get a answer back, it retries the transaction with the very same unique ID, so the server can ignore it the second time, and say that it finished. Because this is a case where transactions happen on a distributed system, it makes more sense to treat the server's knowledge as basic and safe, and let the client be in the fog. If the POS cannot get out of the fog, it should retry. Of course this is hard with a design where you "can't mess with" already very messy POS code (it's design is currently broken regarding concepts of robustness).

What you are trying to achieve (to monitor the underlying connection) will not work for many reasons:

- the connection is designed to be closed upon receiving the reply; this is most commonly indistinguishable from a termination above the IP level,
- HTTP is not designed for warranties of message arrival (i.e. there is no "close the request normally" command that would help you) - this is why HTTP is a bad choice for this protocol,
- PHP+webserver is not good at waiting, if all the former points did not exists, even then it is hard to keep PHP running (e.g. examining any states after the connection has been closed), because it is designed to serve a request, and then forget about it.